# Why am I not able to use @ to reply to some person?

Tags: support

e.g.  I reply to "jim124" by writing "@jim124: Thank you for you answer, but… ".  However, the result is "Thank you for you answer, but… " ignoring "@jim124 ". Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not @reply to a person while commenting on their posts. The owner of the post is always notified of a comment. So the system strips off the @reply in certain cases.

Comment: what is a post? I asked a question first, then he gave an answer. Now I want to comment on his answer. You mean my question and his answer are both posts?

Comment: @trhyt: a post is a question or answer. You commented on his answer, no need to use the @

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `@user` at the beginning of a comment, when `user` is the poster of the post you're commenting on, is automatically stripped off by the system under certain circumstances.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Hmm, somehow I forgot to add that :S Thanks! :)

Comment: Now I realise why it is that when I type "@Name Lastname: Blabla", it gets converted to "Lastname: Blabla".!